# How to mock with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here:

my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        User.all
    end
end
```

my controller spec:

```
  it "" do
    get :index
    User.should_receive(:all) 
  end
```

and yet I get this error:

```
  1) UsersController 
     Failure/Error: User.should_receive(:all)
       (<User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, password_digest: string, remember_token: string) (class)>).all(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

just swap the lines

```
it "" do
  User.should_receive(:all) 
  get :index
end
```

EDIT: "should_receive" tells rspec "from now on, until the end of the spec, User should receive the method :all at least one time", then you call get :index and User actually receives the method

the other way (the way it doesn't work), you call get :index, User receives the method :all and AFTER that you tell rspec "from now on, User should receive the method at least once", the method was called BEFORE the should_receive expectation, that's why it fails

Comment: That did it, but I think I'm missing the point a bit here...how is the User object's `.all` method triggered before the `#index` method is triggered by the `get :index`?

Comment: I'd recommend providing a bit more explanation with your answer - while it may work, it doesn't really convey *why*

Comment: added the explanation, should_receive acts from the moment you invoke it until the end of the spec, that's just how should_receive works and the way it has to be invoked